# Is it possible to create sub-applications in Ruby on Rails 3 or something like slices from Merb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Does Rails 3 have anything akin to slices in Merb, or areas in Django where there is a layer of organization above the controller?  I heard at some point that they may allow hosting one rails app within another but I can't find any information on that in the pre-release material.  Any hints on how to do something like this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? You can _kind of_ have one rails app within another by using plugins

Comment: I'm coming from ASP.NET MVC and there is the concept of "areas" where you can essentially logically group your controllers.  It's more of a development convenience than something the user would care about.  But if you have a large model and a lot of controllers you end up just having them all jumbled in one place...so I'd like to be able to segregate related controllers into their own namespace/folder or...something.  Anyway, what I'm trying to accomplish is better organization of the project when there are many controllers to deal with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right there doesn't seem to be a lot of official documentation on it yet. But yes, you can have application slices -- they're called engines in Rails. Actually they've been available in Rails since 2.3. Currently, you basically make a plugin that has a complete application structure and set up your routes in there to "mount" your app against a specific URL. In Rails 3, engines are basically first-class objects in the Rails stack. I believe they can still be plugins but you will also be able keep it away from your application in a separate gem and require it in your application much more easily. You should be able to find stuff pretty easily on teh Google, but here's an oft-linked but informative reference: https://gist.github.com/af7e572c2dc973add221